# What does "if self is not None" mean in a method?

Tags: python, self

```
class omnimethod(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return functools.partial(self.func, instance)

class Geocoder(object):
        def __init__(self, api_key=None, client_id=None, private_key=None):
            # omitted
            pass

        @omnimethod
        def geocode(
            self,
            address,
            sensor='false',
            bounds='',
            region='',
            language='',
            components=''):
                if self is not None:  # <-- here
                    return GeocoderResult(self.get_data(params=params))
                else:
                    return GeocoderResult(Geocoder.get_data(params=params))
```

Exactly in this case.

I didn't understand. What does this "if self is not None" code snippet mean? What is its place in the case? This self is parameter, in the function parameter. But alone.

Comment: What part in particular do you not understand? `self` is a variable. `is not` is a comparison operation that results in a boolean value. `None` is a value. It pretty much reads like an English sentence: *"if [the value] of `self` is not [equal to] `None` do this otherwise do that"*

Comment: Do you know what the `is` operator does? Do you know what the `not` operator does? Do you know what `None` is? It is worth noting that `a is not b` is syntax sugar for `not (a is b)`.

Comment: Normally, you are using self in context of a class. It could be also relevant to show more context.

Comment: That looks like a way to support the use of static methods.

Comment: @samedbll, where is `omnimethod` imported from?

Comment: @Koterpillar class omnimethod(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return functools.partial(self.func, instance)

Comment: consider self as `struct` in c++

Comment: @samedbll Please put that in the question. Also while you're there, you need to fix the indenting. For reference see [mre].

Comment: @Felix Should clarify that `is` is an identity comparison, not a value comparison, and `None` is a singleton. So in English it would be *"if `self` is not [the] `None` [then ...]"*

Comment: @samedbll please put the complete definition of `omnimethod` in the question.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: I think I have enough context to answer - voting to reopen. @samedbll, I trust you know about the normal Python usage of `self`?

Comment: @Koterpillar Yes, exactly.

Comment: Looks like `omnimethod` allows you to make methods callable either on the class itself (`Geocoder.geocode(...)`) or on the instances (`geocoder = Geocoder(...); geocoder.geocode(...)`). That's why the `self` check is necessary. Further reading: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__

Comment: @Koterpillar Oh okay, it makes sense. I understand and it was actually very good. Your explanation is fine and thank you very much. I will search this issue more.

Comment: @Koterpillar - thanks for the explanation. Can you convert that to an answer?

Comment: @FelixKling - I found the question interesting - why would an instance method check if its `self` parameter is None? The explanation is something I wouldn't have thought of.

Comment: @tdelaney: Agreed and maybe that's what the OP wants to know. But that isn't 100% clear from the question, hence me asking to clarify it (and providing an initial response that shows how the question might get interpreted which gives them a chance to say "oh I totally know that, I want to know xyz").

Comment: It means, someone is making this code more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Usually, it's much simpler to define a single global instance of `Geocoder`, (say `g`), then define a module-level function `geocode` which is simply a wrapper around `g.geocode()`. (See the `logging` module for an example of this kind of structure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`omnimethod` looks to be a decorator intended for a function it's applied to to be invoked either as an instance or a class method.

Let's call the original function `original` and the result of applying the decorator, which becomes the `geocode` attribute of class `Geocoder`, `decorated`.

Consider two calls:

```
Geocoder.geocode("some address")  # 1
geocoder = Geocoder()
geocoder.geocode("some address")  # 2
```

According to the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__):

The call (1) will resolve to:

- `decorated.__get__(None, Geocoder)("some address")`, which returns the original function partially applied to `None`:
- `functools.partial(original, None)("some address")`, which, according to implementation of `partial`, is the same as:
- `original(None, "some address")`

The call (2) will resolve to:

- `decorated.__get__(geocoder, Geocoder)("some address")` (where `geocoder` is an instance of `Geocoder`)
- `functools.partial(original, geocoder)("some address")`
- `original(geocoder, "some address")`

Thus, `self` will be `None` inside the original function if it is invoked as a class method, necessitating the check.